# Requesting Help with Writing an Appropriate Unit Test for My Apex Controller Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller-extension, custom-controller

I need help writing an apex unit test class for my apex controller class that is being used as an extension for a Visual Force page. The function of the class is to query "Intake__c" records and then filter them based on dates fields and a city field to return the filtered values in a variable called "filteredIntakes." Then the controller class passes that collection of records to the VF Page in order for the VF Page to iterate over the collection with an apex:repeat tag. I'm new-ish to writing apex test classes, and I have never written one that involves a controller for a VF page, so I want to make sure I am doing it correctly. Any help (with maybe some examples) would be much appreciated.

**Here is the code for my Apex controller class *PackingListControllerLWC***

```
public with sharing class PackingListControllerLWC {
    public String city{get; set;}

    public String startDate{get; set;}

    public String endDate{get; set;}

    public List<Intake__c> filteredIntakes{get;set;}

        public PackingListControllerLWC(ApexPages.StandardController Controller) {
            city = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('strCity');
            startDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('dtStartDate');
            endDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('dtEndDate');

            Date myStartDate = Date.valueOf(startDate);
            Date myEndDate = Date.valueOf(endDate);

            DateTime dtStartDate = DateTime.newInstance(myStartDate.year(), myStartDate.month(), myStartDate.day());
            DateTime dtEndDate = DateTime.newInstance(myEndDate.year(), myEndDate.month(), myEndDate.day());

            filteredIntakes = getIntakes(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, city);
        }

        public List<Intake__c> getIntakes(DateTime dtStartDate, DateTime dtEndDate, String strCity){

            Date filterStartDate = (dtStartDate.Date());
            Date filterEndDate = dtEndDate.Date();
            String filterCity = strCity; 

            if(String.isNotBlank(filterCity)){
                filteredIntakes = [SELECT Id, Name, Parent_Name__c, Household__c, Delivery_Date__c, Delivery_Time__c, Intake_Status__c, Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Priority__c, Number_of_Families_Served__c, Number_of_Children_Served__c, 
                                     New_Families__c, Diaper_Boxes_Newborn__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_1__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_2__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_3__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_4__c, 
                                     Diaper_Boxes_Size_5__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_6__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_7__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_4T_5T__c,
                                     Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_4T_5T__c, Baby_Wipes_Num__c, Baby_Formula_Num__c, Formula_Type__c, Additional_Notes__c
                                     FROM Intake__c
                                     WHERE Intake_Status__c = 'Approved' AND Partner_Intake__c = TRUE
                                     AND Delivery_Date__c >= :filterStartDate AND Delivery_Date__c <= :filterEndDate
                                     AND Priority__c = :filterCity LIMIT 10];
            } else {
                filteredIntakes = [SELECT Id, Name, Parent_Name__c, Household__c, Delivery_Date__c, Delivery_Time__c, Intake_Status__c, Street_Address__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c, Priority__c, Number_of_Families_Served__c, Number_of_Children_Served__c, 
                                    New_Families__c, Diaper_Boxes_Newborn__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_1__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_2__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_3__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_4__c, 
                                    Diaper_Boxes_Size_5__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_6__c, Diaper_Boxes_Size_7__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_4T_5T__c,
                                    Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_2T_3T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_3T_4T__c, Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_4T_5T__c, Baby_Wipes_Num__c, Baby_Formula_Num__c, Formula_Type__c, Additional_Notes__c
                                    FROM Intake__c
                                    WHERE Intake_Status__c = 'Approved' AND Partner_Intake__c = TRUE
                                    AND Delivery_Date__c >= :filterStartDate AND Delivery_Date__c <= :filterEndDate LIMIT 10];
            }
            for (Intake__c intake : filteredIntakes) {
                System.debug('Filtered Intake Id: ' + intake.Id +'  '+ intake.Name);
            }
            System.debug('Count Record: ' + filteredIntakes.size());
            return filteredIntakes;
        }

    }
```

**Here is the code for the VisualForce Page that feeds the collection of values "FilteredIntakes" into the VisualForce page using an apex:repeat tag.**

```
<apex:page standardController="Intake__c" renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" extensions="PackingListControllerLWC">

    <!-- This counts the number of pages being created through <apex:repeat> loop. -->
    <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" />
    
    <apex:repeat value="{!FilteredIntakes}" var="oneItem">

        <!-- Style attribute here uses logic to stop rendering a final page which is left blank -->
        <div style="{!if(cnt < 1, 'page-break-before:avoid;','page-break-before:always;')}">
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Intake Details">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Name }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Id }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Parent_Name__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Household__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Priority__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Delivery_Date__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Delivery_Time__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!oneItem.Intake_Status__c }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Baby Wipes and Formula">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oneItem}" var="Placeholder" border="2" cellpadding="3" style="text-align: center">
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Baby_Wipes_Num__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Baby_Formula_Num__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Formula_Type__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Diaper Box Sizes">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oneItem}" var="Placeholder" border="2" cellpadding="3" style="text-align: center">
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Newborn__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_1__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_2__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_3__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_4__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_5__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_6__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Diaper_Boxes_Size_7__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Pull Up Sizes">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oneItem}" var="Placeholder" border="2" cellpadding="3" style="text-align: center">
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_2T_3T__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_3T_4T__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Boys_Size_4T_5T__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_2T_3T__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_3T_4T__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
               <apex:column value="{!oneItem.Pull_Ups_Girls_Size_4T_5T__c}" style="text-align: center"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        
        <apex:outputText value="Page {!cnt+1}" style="text-align: center"/>

        <!-- Style attribute here uses logic to stop rendering a final page which is left blank -->            
        <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>

        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**And here is the code for my current unit test class.** It is deploying to my org correctly, but when I run the test in dev console it fails. I am sure it is not setup correctly, but just wanted to provide an example of what I have already tried.

```
@isTest
public class PackingListControllerLWCTest {
    
    @isTest
    static void testGetIntakes() {
        Test.startTest();
        
        Intake__c intake = new Intake__c(Priority__c = 'Pickup Seattle', Delivery_Date__c = date.newInstance(2023, 01, 26));        

        insert intake;          //Insert intake record.
    
        //Initialize controller
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(intake);     
        PackingListControllerLWC testPackingListControllerLWC = new PackingListControllerLWC(sc);
    
        PageReference pageRef = Page.intakePdf;     //For e.g.: Page.HelloWorld
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);               //Set Current Page
    
        testPackingListControllerLWC.getIntakes(date.newInstance(2023, 01, 06), date.newInstance(2023, 01, 26), 'Pickup Seattle');  
        Test.stopTest();
        System.AssertNotEquals(null, testPackingListControllerLWC, 'Controller should not be null');
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the failure? Do you get an assertion error or something else uncaught?

Comment: one thing for sure, you need to set page parameters, see this [q&a](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/48336/2602)

Comment: The failure is "System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null."

"Class.PackingListControllerLWC.<init>: line 15, column 1
Class.PackingListControllerLWCTest.testGetIntakes: line 22, column"

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Q&A!